# Un-focus file input box AFTER file got selected (to validate input)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, validation

I have a bootstrap form with a file input box that is checked on the client-site for valid extensions before submitting.

[image]

```
<div class = "container", id="container">
<form id= "fileinput-form" action="/file" method="POST" >
  <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
   <input class="form-control" type="file" accept=".csv,.txt" name="inputfile" aria-label="file example">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:10px">
   <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-file" type="submit" value="Predict">
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

However, the validation is just triggered **after** the input box was un-focused (or rather by clicking somewhere). Though, I want to have the validation right after the windows dialog box got closed (file got selected) and without the need to un-focus the input box.

```
$("#fileinput-form").validate({

      rules:{
          inputfile: {
          required: true,
          extension: true
          }
      },
      messages:{
          inputfile:{
          required: "Please input a file."
          }
      },

 });});
```

I already tried to add an `onchange` function, without any success... Is there any solution?

```
$("#fileinput-form").on("change",function(e) { 
     console.log('file changed'); 
     $("#fileinput-form").trigger('blur');
     /*$("hidden-input").focus();*/
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might also struggle with that issue, here is a working solution that does its job pretty well:

- adding an empty `div` into the html.

  `<div id="eventresponse"> </div>`
- handing over a text into the `div`.

  ```
  $("#inputfile").bind("change",function(){
        $("#eventresponse").text("Input text here");
  });
  ```
- adding a new style

  ```
  #eventresponse{
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    }
  ```

The `eventresponse` only gets triggered and pops up as soon as the windows dialog box is closed.

[image]

**Note:**
As I am not that familiar with javascript, I implemented the actual validation on the server-site (flask) with an async. fetch call. There is an easier solution in pure javascript, certainly.